# How to include output from ExpressJS res.render in a ZIP file?

Tags: node.js, express, adm-zip

I have a built a method in ExpressJS that exports a document as an HTML page:

```
html: function (req, res) {
    Project.findOne( { req.params.project },
        function (err, project) {
            res.contentType('text/html');
            res.render('exporting/html', { project.name });
        }
    );
},
```

Additionally, I'd like to create a method that includes that generated HTML page, together with some static assets, in a ZIP archive.

Here's my current code:

```
zip: function (req, res) {
    Project.findOne( { req.params.project },
        function (err, project) {
            res.contentType('application/zip');
            res.setHeader('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + project.name + '.zip');
            var zip = new AdmZip();
            zip.addFile("readme.txt", new Buffer("This was inside the ZIP!"));
            //------ Here I'd like to use zip.addFile to include the HTML output from the html method above ------
            res.send(zip.toBuffer());
        }
    );
}
```

How can I make the `zip` method include the output from the `html` method?

Comment: do you want the zip file to be downloaded when somebody hits the html page?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: one is relatively simple and the other is a bit more complicated. You'll have to decide which you believe is which. ;)

### First method

Since you are relying on express' Response.render to create your HTML from a view, you'll need to call that route on your server to retrieve the content of the page so you can include it in your zip response.

Assuming you have `var http=require('http');` somewhere in this file, you can:

```
zip: function (req, res) { 

  var projectId=req.params.project||'';

  if(!projectId){ // make sure we have what we need!
    return res.status(404).send('requires a projectId');
  }

  // Ok, we start by requesting our project...

  Project.findOne({id:projectId},function(err, project) {

    if(err) { // ALWAYS handle errors!
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    if('object'!==typeof project){ // did we get what we expected?
      return res.status(404).send('failed to find project for id: '+projectId);
    }

    var projectName=project.name || ''; // Make no assumptions!

    if(!projectName){
      return res.status(500).send('whoops! project has no name!');
    }

    // For clarity, let's write a function to create our
    // zip archive which will take:
    //   1. a name for the zip file as it is sent to the requester
    //   2. an array of {name:'foo.txt',content:''} objs, and
    //   3. a callback which will send the result back to our 
    //      original requester.

    var createZipArchive=function(name, files, cb){

        // create our zip...
        var zip=new AdmZip();

        // add the files to the zip
        if(Array.isArray(files)){
          files.forEach(function(file){
            zip.addFile(file.name,new Buffer(file.content));
          });
        }

        // pass the filename and the new zip to the callback
        return cb(name, zip);
     };

     // And the callback that will send our response...
     //
     // Note that `res` as used here is the original response
     // object that was handed to our `zip` route handler.

     var sendResult=function(name, zip){
       res.contentType('application/zip');
       res.setHeader('content-disposition','attachment; filename=' + name);
       return res.send(zip.toBuffer());
     };

    // Ok, before we formulate our response, we'll need to get the 
    // html content from ourselves which we can do by making
    // a get request with the proper url. 
    //
    // Assuming this server is running on localhost:80, we can 
    // use this url. If this is not the case, modify it as needed.

    var url='http://localhost:80/html';

    var httpGetRequest = http.get(url,function(getRes){

      var body=''; // we'll build up the result from our request here.

      // The 'data' event is fired each time the "remote" server
      // returns a part of its response. Remember that these data
      // can come in multiple chunks, and you do not know how many, 
      // so let's collect them all into our body var.

      getRes.on('data',function(chunk){
        body+=chunk.toString(); // make sure it's not a Buffer!
      });

      // The 'end' event will be fired when there are no more data 
      // to be read from the response so it's here we can respond
      // to our original request.

      getRes.on('end',function(){

        var filename=projectName+'.zip',
            files=[
              { 
                name:'readme.txt',
                content:'This was inside the ZIP!'
              },{
                name:'result.html',
                content:body
              }
            ];

        // Finally, call our zip creator passing our result sender...
        //
        // Note that we could have both built the zip and sent the 
        // result here, but using the handlers we defined above
        // makes the code a little cleaner and easier to understand.
        // 
        // It might have been nicer to create handlers for all the 
        // functions herein defined in-line...

        return createZipArchive(filename,files,sendResult);
      });

    }).on('error',function(err){
      // This handler will be called if the http.get request fails
      // in which case, we simply respond with a server error.
      return res.status(500).send('could not retrieve html: '+err);
    });
  );
}
```

This is really the best way to solve your problem, even though it might seem complex. Some of the complexity can be reduced by using a better 
HTTP client library like [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) which reduce all the event handling rig-a-ma-roll to a simple:

```
var request = require('superagent');

request.get(url, function(err, res){
  ...
  var zip=new AdmZip();
  zip.addFile('filename',new Buffer(res.text));
  ...
});
```

### Second method

The second method utilizes the `render()` method of express' `app` object, which is exactly what `res.render()` uses to convert views into HTML.

See [Express app.render()](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.render) for how this function operates.

Note that this solution is the same except for the portion annotated starting at `// - NEW CODE HERE -`.

```
zip: function (req, res) { 

  var projectId=req.params.project||'';

  if(!projectId){ // make sure we have what we need!
    return res.status(404).send('requires a projectId');
  }

  // Ok, we start by requesting our project...

  Project.findOne({id:projectId},function(err, project) {

    if(err) { // ALWAYS handle errors!
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    if('object'!==typeof project){ // did we get what we expected?
      return res.status(404).send('failed to find project for id: '+projectId);
    }

    var projectName=project.name || ''; // Make no assumptions!

    if(!projectName){
      return res.status(500).send('whoops! project has no name!');
    }

    // For clarity, let's write a function to create our
    // zip archive which will take:
    //   1. a name for the zip file as it is sent to the requester
    //   2. an array of {name:'foo.txt',content:''} objs, and
    //   3. a callback which will send the result back to our 
    //      original requester.

    var createZipArchive=function(name, files, cb){

        // create our zip...
        var zip=new AdmZip();

        // add the files to the zip
        if(Array.isArray(files)){
          files.forEach(function(file){
            zip.addFile(file.name,new Buffer(file.content));
          });
        }

        // pass the filename and the new zip to the callback
        return cb(name, zip);
     };

     // And the callback that will send our response...
     //
     // Note that `res` as used here is the original response
     // object that was handed to our `zip` route handler.

     var sendResult=function(name, zip){
       res.contentType('application/zip');
       res.setHeader('content-disposition','attachment; filename=' + name);
       return res.send(zip.toBuffer());
     };

     // - NEW CODE HERE - 

     // Render our view, build our zip and send our response...
     app.render('exporting/html', { name:projectName }, function(err,html){
       if(err){
         return res.status(500).send('failed to render view: '+err);
       }

       var filename=projectName+'.zip',
           files=[
             { 
               name:'readme.txt',
               content:'This was inside the ZIP!'
             },{
               name:'result.html',
               content:html
             }
           ];


       // Finally, call our zip creator passing our result sender...
       //
       // Note that we could have both built the zip and sent the 
       // result here, but using the handlers we defined above
       // makes the code a little cleaner and easier to understand.
       // 
       // It might have been nicer to create handlers for all the 
       // functions herein defined in-line...

       return createZipArchive(filename,files,sendResult);
    });
}
```

While this method is somewhat shorter, by utilizing the underlying mechanism that Express uses to render views, it "couples" your `zip` route to the Express engine in such a way that, should the Express API change in the future, you'll need to make two changes to your server code (to properly handle the `html` route and the `zip` routes), rather than only one using the previous solution.

Personally, I favor the first solution as it is cleaner (in my mind) and more independent of unexpected change. But as they say [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary) ;).